# How to read destination path after the SaveAs UI is used

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro running in the Workbook BeforeSave event

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If SaveAsUI = True Then
         'read destination path somehow
         'perform business logic using the destination folder
    End If
End Sub
```

Certain validation on the workbook content need to take place only if the file is saved to a certain destination, this may result in the save action being cancelled.

I have been unable to find a way to read what the user specified as the destination path. I need some help please as I am not a VBA specialist.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me the event fires before a destination path is chosen. You probably have to use the WorkbookAfterSave event and then perform the validation afterwards.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.workbookaftersave

Comment: No Sir, I don't believe you are correct. I am running the latest Office 365. When I click Save As under the File menu I get the rather specific Excel version of the "save as" dialog. The before save event is called only after I click on the Save button on the Save As dialog window. Therefore, I think the software knows the destination path and name already.

Comment: If the user clicks Browse on the Save As dialog, the BeforeSave event fires immediately before a folder can be chosen.

However if the user clicks a "pinned" folder from the list of previously used folders, the event does not fire until the user subsequently clicks the Save button on the Save As dialog. Nevertheless, I don't believe Excel provides any means of determining which folder was chosen in the dialog. Of course if the save is not canceled, the path can be obtained from ActiveWorkbook.Path.

Comment: You may disable the ability to use Save and Save As. Changes to an existing workbook may still be saved on close per the scenario in the following link. To provide an alternative means of Saving As in which the path is validated would probably require a custom procedure that displays the folder or file browser control and then saves if appropriate. https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3611-excel-disable-do-not-allow-save.html